# Azure AD application - Can it be part of a Security Group?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am creating a rest API which I am securing using OAuth2 client-credentials flow in Azure Active Directory. This requires me to set up the clients who should get access to my API as applications in Azure AD.

I would really like to take the AD thing a step further and have SQL Database access using AD Security Groups.

The question is; can I add an AD application to a security group and get Azure Active Directory login to work?

Comment: You means add the users defined in your Azure Ad in a on promise AD ?

Comment: No. When setting up a web service with client-credentials flow in Azure AD, it is registered as an application in order to get a secret key. But I cannot see how I can add this application to an Azure AD security group so that I can use integrated security with Azure SQL Database.

Comment: I don't think it is possible but I am not sure at all